# python list comprehensions invalid syntax while if statement

Tags: python, string, list, list-comprehension

I've got list like this `z = ['aaaaaa','bbbbbbbbbb','cccccccc']` i would like to cut off first 6 chars from all elements and if element is empty not to put in another list. So I made this code:

`[x[6:] if x[6:] is not '' else pass for x in z]`

I've tried with

`pass`
`continue`

and still syntax error. Maybe someone could help me with it? thanks

Comment: Your title is a bit misleading: the question has nothing to do with lambda functions.  Were you thinking of list comprehensions?

Comment: OK, I changed title, thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whenever you need to filter items from a list, the condition has to be at the end. So you need to filter the empty items, like this

```
[x[6:] for x in z if x[6:] != ""]
# ['bbbb', 'cc']
```

Since, an empty string is falsy, we can write the same condition succinctly as follows

```
[x[6:] for x in z if x[6:]]
```

As an alternative, as tobias_k suggested, you can check the length of the string like this

```
[x[6:] for x in z if len(x) > 6]
```

Comment: +1 Alternatively, `if len(x) > 6` might be a tiny bit faster?

Comment: Ultimatively `if x[6:]` is shorter ;) Also it's as fast as len(x) > 6 afaik.

Comment: @tobias_k Included that suggestion in the answer. Thanks :)

Comment: @Vladimir Indeed, `x[6:]` (without `!= ''`) is even a bit faster. Still, I think using `len` is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are learning to do with [lambda](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk)(not an official link), you should try with map and filter like this:

```
filter(None, map(lambda y: y[6:], x))
```

Here, the map(lambda y: y[6:], x) will keep only strings from 7th character and replace other smaller strings with Boolean 'False'. To remove all these 'False' values from the new list, we will use filter function.

You can take this only for learning purposes as this is downright ugly when Python's [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) is considered. List comprehension is the way to go like mentioned above.

```
[y[6:] for y in x if y[6:]]
```

Or the traditional for loop as

```
output = []
for y in x:
    if isinstance(y, str) and y[6:]:
        output.append(y[6:])
```

Please note that even though the traditional way looks bigger, it can add more values(like here, taking only the strings from the list if the list has other data types such as lists, tuples, dictionaries, etc)

So I would suggest either to stick with list comprehensions for simple controlled lists or the traditional way for controlled output